# Showing $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{j}\big(1-\frac{c\ln n}n\big)^{j(n-j)}=0$ for $c>1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I want to show that $\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{j}\left(1-\frac{c\ln n}n\right)^{j(n-j)}$ converges to $0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, where $c>1$ is a constant and $\ln$ is the natural logarithm. This is true numerically, but I do not know how one could go about analyzing this mathematically.

*Attempt 1*: If I boldly assume for now $\left(1-\frac{c\ln n}n\right)^{n} \cdot e^{-c\ln n} \rightarrow 1$ (motivated by the limit of exp; not sure how to justify this) and use $\frac{n}{n^c}<1$, I get an upper bound: $\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \frac{n^{(1-c)j}}{j!}$. Next, if I again boldly assume that $\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \frac{n^{(1-c)j}}{j!}\;\right) \cdot (e^{n^{1-c}} - 1)^{-1}  \rightarrow 1$ (motivated by the limit of the infinite series form of exp), it would be done. However, I do not know how to justify my bold assumptions (actually I think they are wrong).

*Attempt 2*: I tried using Stirling's approximation to control the binomial coefficient, but I don't know how to control the summation. If I further bound the coefficient by taking the maximum of $j\in \{1,...,n-1\}$, the bound diverges.

Comment: what does $cln(n)$ means?

Comment: $ln$ is the natural log, and c is the constant provided (which is known to be greater than 1)

Comment: Then, you should change ''cln(n)'' to ''c\ln(n)'' otherwise is hard to understand you.

Comment: Sure thing. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Regarding my answer: $j<n/2$ is still correct, because if [$n$ is odd and] $j=(n-1)/2$ then $a_{n,j}=a_{n,j+1}$. *(So there's no need to make it $j<(n-1)/2$, but no harm either.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *Attempt 1* needs some correction (the *upper bound* doesn't look valid). Denote $$b_n=1-\frac{c\ln n}n,\quad a_{n,j}=\binom{n}{j}b_n^{j(n-j)},\quad s_n=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}a_{n,j}$$ (where $c\geqslant 1$ is fixed; we allow $c=1$ *for now*).

Clearly $a_{n,j}=a_{n,n-j}$ and, for large enough $n$, since $1-x\leqslant e^{-x}$ for $x\geqslant 0$, $$a_{n,j}\leqslant\frac{n^j}{j!}e^{-cj(1-j/n)\ln n}=\frac1{j!}n^{(1-c)j+cj^2/n}\tag{*}\label{upperbound}$$ (this is the *corrected* upper bound I mean).

---

Next, we show that for large enough $n$, and any $j<(n-1)/2$, we have $a_{n,j}\geqslant a_{n,j+1}$.

Indeed, suppose that $j<(n-1)/2$ and $a_{n,j}<a_{n,j+1}$. Then $a_{n,j+1}/a_{n,j}>1$ leads to
\begin{align}
\frac{n-j}{j+1}b_n^{n-2j-1} &>1 \\
(n-2j-1)\ln(b_n)&> -\ln(\frac{n-j}{j+1}) \\
(n+1)\ln(b_n)&> \frac{n+1}{n-2j-1}\ln(\frac{j+1}{n-j}) \\
(n+1)\ln b_n&>f\left(\frac{j+1}{n+1}\right),\quad f(r)=\frac1{1-2r}\ln\frac{r}{1-r}.
\end{align}

The function $f(r)$ is increasing for $0<r<1/2$ *(consider $f(1/2-x)$ as a power series in $x$)*, thus $(n+1)\ln b_n>f\big(1/(n+1)\big)$, i.e. $(n-1)\ln b_n+\ln n>0$ *(this is the same as $a_{n,1}>1$)*.

But, as $n\to\infty$, the latter becomes impossible, since $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n\big((n-1)\ln b_n+\ln n\big)=-\infty$.

---

Now we take $k<(n-1)/2$ and split the sum $s_n=2\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}a_{n,j}+\sum_{j=k}^{n-k}a_{n,j}$, which gives $$2\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}a_{n,j}\leqslant s_n\leqslant 2\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}a_{n,j}+na_{n,k}.$$

For $c>1$, we choose $k>1/(c-1)$; then \eqref{upperbound} implies $0 \leq na_{n,k} \leq n^{1-k(c-1)} \frac{1}{k!}\left(n^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)^{ck^2} \to 0$ and $a_{n,j}\to 0$ for all $j$ as $n\to\infty$, hence $\color{red}{s_n\to 0}$ as needed (moreover, we get $n^{c-1}s_n\to 2$ since only $a_{n,1}$ tends to 1 in the bounds).

For $c=1$ we have $a_{n,j}\to 1/j!$ for a fixed $j$, but the choice of a *fixed* $k$ leads to nothing. Instead, using $k=\lfloor n^{1/3}\rfloor$ (to have $k^2/n\to 0$) and [DCT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tannery%27s_theorem), we get $s_n\to 2(e-1)$ in this case.